# EF core - Remove a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to remove a table from the database because it's not needed anymore, but I still need the entity in the code.

I removed the entity from DbSet in the context:

```
// public virtual DbSet<DocumentInfo> DocumentInfos { get; set; }
```

But when I add a migration, I got this error :

> The entity type 'DocumentInfo' requires a primary key to be defined.

Why does it try to do anything with that entity if I don't specify it in the dbcontext ?

I don't want this table in the database anymore, how should I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have removed / commented all of the references of the model class (to be removed) that are mentioned in other model classes.

Comment: Ok it was that, it's still used by an other entity. Thank you !